# Setting a Windows variable to execute a Java program

Tags: java, command-prompt

I am setting this variable

```
set srcDir = C:\Developpement\Workspaces\Eclipse\MyAuthenticationProvider\src
```

Then I execute this program

```
java -DMJF=MyAuthentication.jar -Dfiles=%srcDir% weblogic.management.commo.WebLogicMBeanMaker
```

But I have this strange error

```
The specified input files directory, "%srcDir%", does not exist.
```

I even tried using

```
java -DMJF=MyAuthentication.jar -Dfiles=$srcDir weblogic.management.commo.WebLogicMBeanMaker
```

with the same result

```
The specified input files directory, "$srcDir", does not exist.
```

another test:

```
C:\Developpement\Workspaces\Eclipse\WLAuthenticationProvider>set a=test

C:\Developpement\Workspaces\Eclipse\WLAuthenticationProvider>echo $a
$a

C:\Developpement\Workspaces\Eclipse\WLAuthenticationProvider>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Currently, you are setting the srcDir with

```
set srcDir = C:\Developpement\Workspaces\Eclipse\MyAuthenticationProvider\src
```

Remove the spaces

```
set srcDir=C:\Developpement\Workspaces\Eclipse\MyAuthenticationProvider\src
```

I believe your original command will then work.

```
java -DMJF=MyAuthentication.jar -Dfiles=%srcDir% weblogic.management.commo.WebLogicMBeanMaker
```